# php read and write to file fails

Tags: php, bash, cron

I am trying to spam myself with push messages when there is a sudden difference in power consumption that exceeds a threshold.
I collect data every minute. A cronjob collects data from my SMA converter and from my smart meter.
These data are put in character strings.
With that I do some subtraction and the collected outcome is put into a file.
At the next one minute interval new data are collected.
The old result is extracted from the file.
Comparision from old and new showes if the threshold is passed.
The newest result is then put into the file again.
The file is called usage.txt

```
if (!$handle = file_get_contents('/home/pi/test/usage.txt'))
{
    // failure
    echo "error opening the file usage.txt for reading",PHP_EOL;
}
else
{
    $lastusage=$handle;
    echo ' Last usage and current usage`           :  '.$lastusage.' '.$currentusage, PHP_EOL   ;
}

if(!file_put_contents("/home/pi/test/usage.txt",$currentusage))
{
    // failure
    echo "error opening the file usage.txt for writing",PHP_EOL;
}
```

This reading and writing doesn't trigger error mesages, but inside the usage.txt file the 10 is writen and not 630 or 1240 which is the actual character string that I expect to be inserted in usage.txt.

Comment: Shouldn't it be if ($handle != file ......

Comment: Just FYI, in Linux if a file is opened an flock is put in place so it cannot be opened by another application. In other words a text file might not be the best way to sync the data (or copy the file and open that one instead). Secondly, where is `$lastusage` and `$currentusage` defined?

Comment: Can you tell me what would be a better way to memorise the $lastusage ?  Where can I find an example ?

Comment: What does the `echo ' Last usage and current usage…` output exactly?